# How can I chat while watching a video on MPC at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, instant-messaging, media-player-classic

To be specific, is there any way to instant message/chat that lets you use a shortcut and have it appear overlayed on Media Player Classic when it's in fullscreen. I'd also prefer it be semi-transparent and have a sound notification whenever someone sends a message.

Comment: No; there isn't

Comment: closest thing would be to run MPC not on top, or get a program that sets specific windows to "pin to top" or "always on Top" and use a chat program that has built in transparency like http://help.trillian.im/discussions/windows/13744-how-do-i-change-transparency-for-chat-windows Trillian used to have that, i do not know if it still does. ATI "glass" or "hydravision" desktop manager had a full window transparency ability for any and all windows long before win7 , but it was not used by anyone, and is probably fully obsolete now. It had issues with some window types and skins too.